# Get value for gpu current and max frequency in android

Tags: java, android, android-studio, gpu

I am able to get gpu max frequency /sys/class/kgsl/kgsl-3d0/max_gpuclk which is 840000000 for me

But when i try to get gpu current frequency from this /sys/class/kgsl/kgsl-3d0/gpuclk i get error this error -> gpuinfo java.io.FileNotFoundException: /sys/class/kgsl/kgsl-3d0/gpuclk: open failed: EACCES (Permission denied)

I have tried with allowing all the permissions.

```
try {
        Log.d(
            "GPU Info",
            "gpuinfo test max" + getGPUFreq("/sys/class/kgsl/kgsl-3d0/max_gpuclk")
        )
        Log.d(
            "GPU Info",
            "gpuinfo test curr" + getGPUFreq("/sys/class/kgsl/kgsl-3d0/gpuclk")
        )
        val gpuFile = File("/sys/class/kgsl/kgsl-3d0/gpuclk")
        if (gpuFile.exists()) {
            val fis = FileInputStream(gpuFile)
            val reader = BufferedReader(InputStreamReader(fis))
            var line: String
            while (reader.readLine().also { line = it } != null) {
                // 'line' contains the content of the file
                // You can process or display the content as needed
                // For example, you can log it:
                Log.d("GPU Info", "gpuinfo$line")
            }

            // Close the resources when done
            reader.close()
            fis.close()
        } else {
            // Handle the case where the file does not exist
            Log.d("GPU Info", "gpuinfo he file does not exist")
        }
    } catch (e: java.lang.Exception) {
        // Handle exceptions appropriately
        e.printStackTrace()
        Log.d("GPU Info", "gpuinfo $e")
    }




 fun getGPUFreq(path: String): Int? {
    return readIntegerFile(path)
}

private fun readIntegerFile(path: String): Int? {
    var ret = 0
    try {
        val reader = RandomAccessFile(path, "r")
        ret = try {
            val line = reader.readLine()
            line.toInt()
        } finally {
            reader.close()
        }
    } catch (ex: Exception) {
        ex.printStackTrace()
    }
    return ret
}
```